# vector of string, need to search for a particular character in it

Tags: c++, string, vector, find

I have a vector of strings, i need to search for a particular character in it

```
vector<string> users;

users.push_back("user25_5");
users.push_back("user65_6");
users.push_back("user95_9");
```

I have to search for the number 65 in the vector
the find library of vectors just searches for the entire string, it does not work for particular character in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable functor:

```
bool has_65(const std::string& s)
{
  // search for "65" and return bool
}
```

then

```
auto it = std::find_if(users.begin(), users.end(), has_65);
```

For finding strings inside strings, have a look at [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: `std::fund_if(us.economy(), [&] { return rep.votes() < dem.votes(); });`

Comment: @KerrekSB but at least you used a lambda :D

Comment: so I have place the auto it = xxx inside an iterator, because I want to search for list of numbers in the vector

Comment: auto it = std::find_if(user.begin(), user.end(), has_65);
    cout<<*it<<endl;

in my has_65
if(s.find("65")){
return true;}

when i cout *it, it displays the first vector value

Comment: So, what is with the down-vote? Something seriously wrong with this answer, beside the obvious typo?

Comment: @meWantToLearn you should read the documentation for `std::string::find`. I included a link in my answer.